# PHP's in_array bevahior surprises me

Tags: php

While validating a dynamic saving method in a controller I wanted to make sure a given case only accepts 0 and 1 as valid values. When I tried to manipulate the input form, submitting 'aaa' as a value the following still returns true. Why is that?

```
var_dump(in_array('aaa', [0, 1])); // true, I was expecting it to return false
```

Comment: Check the documentation for the third parameter of `in_array`.

Comment: PHP is a weak typed language...

Comment: @DCoder, I'm aware of the third parameter but how does 'aaa' relate to either 0 or 1 in a non-strict mode.

Comment: @Ben Try `var_dump(0 == 'aaa');`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use the "strict" setting, to force the function to check the types of the elements as well:

```
var_dump(in_array('aaa', [0, 1], true));
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php states

> If the third parameter strict is set to TRUE then the in_array()
>   function will also check the types of the needle in the haystack.

The reason it returns true is because a string is truthy, and so is `1`.

```
if( "aaa" ){ echo "you will see me"; }
```